# Referencing inner Generics type

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to extract inner generic types?

Imagine the following classes:

```
interface Animal { }

class Bear implements Animal { }

class AnimalRule<ANIMAL extends Animal> { }

class BearRule extends AnimalRule<Bear> { }
```

Now I want to write tests for this code, but I want to have a generic base test class.

I can declare it this way:

```
class AnimalRuleAltTest<ANIMAL extends Animal, RULE extends AnimalRule<ANIMAL>> {
  RULE rule;
  ANIMAL animal;
}

class BearRuleAltTest extends AnimalRuleAltTest<Bear, BearRule> { }
```

However I must pass both `Bear` and `BearRule`, which seems superfluous as the compiler surely knows that `BearRule` already implements `AnimalRule<`**Bear**`>`.

---

Would it be possible to somehow extract the inner generic type if I provide just the rule class?

Something like this:

```
class AnimalRuleTest<RULE extends AnimalRule<ANIMAL>> {
  RULE rule;
  ANIMAL animal;
}

class BearRuleTest extends AnimalRuleTest<BearRule> { }
```

---

Update: Just to be clear, I am asking about extracting inner classes/whether it is possible, not how to "fix" it.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't show how you're using the `BearRule` side of the type parameters in the test class. That makes me ask why not just make it `AnimalRuleAltTest<ANIMAL extends Animal>`?

Comment: @ernest_k ah, sorry. I need both in the test. I've updated the code.

Comment: I know of no static/compile-time construct to achieve that. The compiler will just validate the relationship for you, but you'll have to declare a type (parameter) statically before using it as a variable's data type. It would be possible if the two types led to a runtime relationship, such as composition (like a `bearRule` has a `bear`), but you'd still be unable to declare a variable by an inferred type at compile time.

Comment: A question please, why do you need a generic base class for the test ? unit tests should test the implementation  as far as i know, will you need to instantiate each one seperatly ? if yes for what matter ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI whether it is Test or not is not relevant to the question.

Comment: I already managed to do that, in output  i get a Class object, is this what do you want to achieve  ?

Comment: No, you can't query type params statically. However, you can do it dynamically, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54368840/1876620).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class AnimalRuleAltTest<ANIMAL extends Animal> {
    AnimalRule<ANIMAL> rule;
    ANIMAL animal;
}

class BearRuleAltTest extends AnimalRuleAltTest<Bear> { }
```

Also, replace all occurences of `RULE` in `AnimalRuleAltTest` with `AnimalRule<ANIMAL>`.

Comment: I know I can do this, but it is in principle no different to the version I was avoiding. I want to extract the inner generics, not introduce more classes.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet, following the exact same structure of yours, goes from the `BearRuleTest` to get the `Bear`.

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws Exception {

        final ParameterizedType bearRuleTestGenericSuperclass =
            (ParameterizedType) BearRuleTest.class.getGenericSuperclass();
        final Type type = bearRuleTestGenericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        final ParameterizedType animalRuleGenericSuperclass =
            (ParameterizedType) Class.forName(type.getTypeName()).getGenericSuperclass();

        System.out.println(
            animalRuleGenericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]
        );
    }
```

**edit:**

- I first get the your ruleTest generic superclass, which is `AnimalRuleTest` with an `AnimalRule`.
- Then I get the first argument, which is `BearRule`.
- I load from the classloader the `BearRule` class, then get its `genericSuperclass`, which is `AnimalRule` with a generic parameter.
- Then I take the first arg which is the `Bear`.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. OP doesn't want to find out the generic types dynamically, i.e. at runtime. Instead, they're asking if there's a way to not declare the explicit `Animal` in the most concrete test `BearRuleTest` (here this would be `Bear`), as it's already known to the compiler because of the other generic type param (`BearRule` in this case, which happens to be an `AnimalRule<Bear>`).

Comment: I see, but I still lack the reason behind seeking statically the concrete `Animal` implementation since we know that the `BearRuleTest` is concerning a `BEAR`.

Comment: OP just wants to avoid typing `Bear` as an extra generic type. I mean, when declaring the class.